# Vertices of a cyclic polygon have integer coordinates and sides. If odd $n$ divides the squares of the sides, it divides twice the area.

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, analytic-geometry, polygons

IMO 2016 Problem 3:

> Let $P = A_1 A_2 \cdots A_k$ be a convex polygon in the plane. The vertices $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_k$ have integral coordinates and lie on a circle. Let $S$ be the area of $P$. An odd positive integer $n$ is given such that the squares of the side lengths of $P$ are integers divisible by $n$. Prove that $2S$ is an integer divisible by $n$.

I tried using the [formula for area of a polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) in cartesian plane, after assuming coordinates, but to no avail.

Comment: the solutions I have seen do it for $n=p^a$ with $p$ an odd prime and induction over $k$.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855759/imo-2016-p3-number-theory-with-the-area-of-a-polygon

Comment: [link](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1270467p6637660)

Answer (score 0):

Incomplete proof

Since $P$ is convex, we can uniquely truncate $P$ with right-angled triangles with hypotenuses equal to the side lengths of $P$ and the remaining rectilinears inside.

Let reducible triangle be a right-angled triangle with Pythagorean triple $(a,b,c)$ where both $a$,$b$ and $c$ are divisible by $n$.

If all triangles above truncating $P$ is reducible triangles, area of each triangle and rectilinear is divisible by $n^2$. Thus, $2S$ must be divisible by $n$.

Please figure out the case with $P$ truncated by some non-reducible triangles.